# CORSについて

Tags: google-chrome, flask, cors

開発環境：Windows 10, VSCode, flaskでWEB開発しています。

html内にstaticフォルダからjsファイルを読み込ませているのですが、読込エラーが発生するようになりました。

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='javascript/code_bumon_reload.js')}}"></script>
```

フォルダ構成は以下の通りで、appフォルダの中にルーティング用のpyファイルがあり、staticフォルダの中にjsファイルが複数配置しています。
templateフォルダはjinja用のhtmlファイルを置いています。

```
--app
   |---static
   |---template
```

リクエストurlは `http://127.0.0.1:5000/approval/closed/bumon` となっていますが、リロードする度に全く異なるjsファイルに対してCORSエラーが発生します。
規則性がありません。

##### エラー内容

```
Access to script at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/statics/jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxnotification.js' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request had a target IP address space of `unknown` yet the resource is in address space `local`.
bumon:25          GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/statics/jqwidgets/jqwidgets/jqxnotification.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Chromeでエラーが発生したjsファイルのリクエストは以下の表示でした。

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: session=.eJw9jstOxDAMAP8l5z3YcZxHfyaKY0esgIKaVloJ8e-EFeI6h5n5cnUcNl_cdh6X3Vy9q9tcjhS5AIsRxmEdGowi2lPvCdSzMYUcBhOVJhaCSbbY48gNik-FMGMjICLjjqnHFIRSYh3AXlibFUy-FPOYIahfpYToJbYACgDRrZFPO97bbvvpttHe5u_bNe14DiJEurk-j1HPj1fb1zL3oRBwcBMS0UTeugbgQaEYKCsxYxNY6vusKtUe1q_T9F-_8LxW9Zn5o98_hx9WFA.YqXHXQ.7XdCtBy4gWkSyV9Zb-lQkgd2_4Y
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 18 Feb 2022 08:06:15 GMT
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5000/approval/closed/bumon
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36
```

Chromeのリクエストヘッダーではsame-originとなっているのに、エラーとしてはCORSが発生しているのが理解できませんでした。また読み込むタイミングによっては同じ環境下でもCORSエラーが全く発生しなくて正常に完了します。

エラー内容の中にある「ip address space」という言葉が気になりますが、この症状がローカル環境だけに限定されていればよいのですが、本番環境に引きずると問題になると思いましてご質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Fiddler などのキャプチャツールを使って要求・応答ヘッダがどのようになっているかを調べることをお勧めします。解決のためのヒントが見つかると思います。

Comment: Chrome 特有の問題なのですか？